# Finding a tricky limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I have a homework in real analysis and I'm very confused about it. I would be very thankful, if you could give me any ideas or solutions how to get this task done. The task is as follows:

> Find the limit:
>   $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x} \int_{0}^{x} (1+ \sin(t))^{1/t} dt.$$

A hint that has been given is to use L'Hospital's Rule. Moreover, it must be substantiated why we can use L'Hospital' Rule in this situation. It is also important to mention that $(1 + \sin(t))$ has a removable point of discontinuity at $0$ and therefore the integral can be interpreted as a Riemann integral.

Comment: the Limit is $e$

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $$f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}(1+\sin t) ^{1/t}\,dt=\int_{0}^{x}g(t)\,dt$$ then the limit in question is $f'(0)$. By fundamental theorem of calculus we have $f'(0)=g(0)$ provided $g$ is continuous at $0$. Luckily the integrand has a removable discontinuity at $0$ and by defining $$g(0)=\lim_{t\to 0}(1+\sin t) ^{1/t}=e$$ we can ensure that $g$ is continuous at $0$ and therefore $f'(0)=g(0)=e$.

---

Usage of L'Hospital's Rule is totally unnecessary here and I wonder why L'Hospital's Rule was given as a hint. Also the fact that the integrand $(1+\sin t) ^{1/t}$ has a removable discontinuity at $0$ is important to get an answer to this question, but it is not needed for "interpreting the given integral as a Riemann integral". A Riemann integrable function can have non-removable discontinuity. However a Riemann integrable function can not have an infinite discontinuity (like $1/x$ at $x=0$) because it must be bounded.

Comment: Do you leave out this $1/x$?

Comment: @M.Smithy: yes $1/x$ is not integrable over any interval containing $0$.